# apply function to every element in data.frame and return data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, element, apply

UPDATE: before, I used the `paste` function as an example instead of an arbitrary `myFun` function. That problem was slightly easier, because `paste` can actually operate on vectors, while `myFun` can not.

I would like to apply my own function element-wise to every element in a data.frame, and get the modified data.frame as a return value.

Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))
> df
  c.1..2..3. c.2..3..4.
1          1          2
2          2          3
3          3          4
> df_x <- magical_apply_function(df, function(x) myFun
> df_x
  c.1..2..3. c.2..3..4.
1         myFun(1)         myFun(2)
2         myFun(2)         myFun(3)
3         myFun(3)         myFun(4)
```

I'm completely baffled to not be able to find the answer to this problem anywhere on the internet. Most resources talk about `apply`, `lapply`, and `sapply` but those only work on vectors/lists and they only return lists.

Are for loops really the only way to go here?

Comment: Just use `lapply`, q.v. the @akrun answer below.

Comment: Notwithstanding the solutions below I'm baffled why you are baffled. It's the raison d'être of data.frames to collect disparate data. Although paste works here if you can apply the function to the whole DF then usually it should be a matrix.

Comment: bonus: the function to be applied can NOT handle vectors

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) paste(x,"x", sep=""))
df
```

`df[]` preserves the dataframe's structure.

Comment: when I do something similar to this (same rationale, different function(x)) I get an Error stating that
    arguments imply differing number of rows: 3877, 3890, 3884, 3925, 4024, 3942, 2758, 4042, 4796, 7297
I'm using an unlist() function inside of myFun and I think it's screwing up the lengths, because its operating on a list of lists.

Comment: holy moly, indeed, the unlist() function unlists more than just one level of listing.

Comment: the solution to that second problem is to use unlist() with option recursive=F and then everything works out.

Answer (score 10):

We can either use `mutate_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate_all(funs(paste0(., "x")))
```

Or with `lapply` from `base R` and convert it to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(lapply(df, paste0,  "x"))
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you not use `apply(df, c(1,2), myFun)`? Using the `c(1,2)` will apply the function to each item in your dataframe individually:

> MARGIN a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns.

```
> temp<-data.frame(le=LETTERS[1:3], nu=20:22)
> temp
  le nu
1  A 20
2  B 21
3  C 22
> apply(temp, c(1,2), function(x) {gsub('d',x,'d1d1')})
     le     nu      
[1,] "A1A1" "201201"
[2,] "B1B1" "211211"
[3,] "C1C1" "221221"
```

The function isn't used correctly if you apply the function by rows:

```
> apply(temp, 1, function(x) {gsub('d',x,'d1d1')})
[1] "A1A1" "B1B1" "C1C1"
Warning messages:
1: In gsub("d", x, "d1d1") :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In gsub("d", x, "d1d1") :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In gsub("d", x, "d1d1") :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: The curly brackets can be omitted `apply(temp, c(1,2), function(x) gsub('d',x,'d1d1'))`

Comment: By the way, this solution is the only one in the thread that really answers the question

Answer (score 3):

See also these `purrr` functions

```
library(purrr)
modify(df,paste0,"x") # output is of the same type input, so `data.frame` here

#   c.1..2..3. c.2..3..4.
# 1         1x         2x
# 2         2x         3x
# 3         3x         4x

map_df(df,paste0,"x") # output is always tibble

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   c.1..2..3. c.2..3..4.
#        <chr>      <chr>
# 1         1x         2x
# 2         2x         3x
# 3         3x         4x
```

Comment: Does `modify` work cell by cell ? I thought it works across columns

Comment: You're right, but the question was updated after answers and first used paste, and the solution which was accepted works the same. The `apply` solution you commented on doesn't really answer the question because it returns a matrix, but `df[] <- apply(...)` (with square brackets) might do the trick.

Comment: Still, this solution is the closest to a good answer to the current question